# Side navigation bar won't stay open with onclick. Have to hold down the button for it to open and stay open

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, sidebar

I am trying to get my side navigation bar to stay open with an onclick function.

JS:

```
 <script>
let btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
let sidenav = document.querySelector(".sidenav");
    
btn.onclick = function(){
    sidenav.className.toggle("active");
    
}
</script>
```

This is working except the class won't stay active. As soon as I unclick my mouse the toggle goes away and the navigation bar goes back to being condensed.

HTML

```
<div class="sidenav">
        <div class="logo_content">
            <div class="logo">
                <i class='bx bx-book-bookmark'></i>
                <div class="logoName">Company Title</div>
            </div>
            <i class='bx bx-menu' id="btn"></i>
        </div>
```

Here is the CSS for the widening of the border around the navigation

```
.sidenav{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 78px;
    box-shadow: -1px -2px 30px black;
    padding: 6px 14px;
    border: 4px white solid;
    border-radius: 20px;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.sidenav:active{
    width: 240px;
    
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `stopPropagation` or using `addEventListener` instead of assigning function to `onclick`? Please also provide the minimal reproducible example of your HTML and CSS for this sidenav.

Comment: The video I was watching was changing the class name for "sidenav" to "sidenav active" which is what that function is supposed to do

Comment: It's for the css. When there's `active` the css should display it on its place, otherwise it will be put in the invisible spot

Comment: I added some of the css so you can see

Comment: you need to use onclick event hander. \

Answer (score 0):

You can't really toggle the pseudo class such as `:active` or `:hover`. You can add another class for it just like `sidenav-active` on the snippet below. Also there's no such function `toggle` for the `className`. You can toggle the `classList` instead. For example:

```
elem.classList.toggle()
```

Working example:

```js
let btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
let sidenav = document.querySelector(".sidenav");
    
btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    sidenav.classList.toggle("sidenav-active");
    if(sidenav.classList.contains("sidenav-active")){
      btn.innerText = "Shrink";
    } else btn.innerText = "Expand";
});
```

```css
.sidenav{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 78px;
    box-shadow: -1px -2px 30px black;
    padding: 6px 14px;
    border: 4px white solid;
    border-radius: 20px;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.sidenav-active{
    width: 240px;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="sidenav">
  <div class="logo_content">
      <div class="logo">
          <i class='bx bx-book-bookmark'></i>
          <div class="logoName">Company Title</div>
      </div>
      <button id="btn">Expand</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a class `.active` and you can use `object.classList.toggle("active")`

*Snippet*

```js
let btn = document.querySelectorAll("[toggleMenu]");
let sidenav = document.querySelector(".sidenav");
    
for(var x=0; x < btn.length; x++){
  btn[x].onclick = function(){
    sidenav.classList.toggle("active"); 
    if(sidenav.classList.contains("active")){
      this.innerHTML = "Collspand";
    }
    else{
      this.innerHTML = "Expand";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.sidenav{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    width: 78px;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: -1px -2px 30px black;
    padding: 6px 14px;
    border: 4px white solid;
    border-radius: 20px;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    background:#fff;
}

.sidenav.active{
    width: 240px;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="sidenav">
        <div class="logo_content">
            <div class="logo">
                <i class='bx bx-book-bookmark'></i>
                <div class="logoName">Company Title</div>
            </div>
            <br>
              <button toggleMenu>Expand</button>  

        </div>
</div>

<div class="body">
</div>
```